# torch.nn.Transformer huge memory impact

Tags: memory, pytorch, encoder-decoder

I'm trying to use a Transformers Encoder as part of my model, something like this:

```
self.trans = torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
            d_model=18, nhead=6, dim_feedforward=64), num_layers=6)
```

Now, I'm not sure if this is normal, but with batches of 256, each batch with a sequence of 62 items of size 18, it fills my 8 Gigs of RAM (on CPU). This seems excessive to me, even for Transformers standards. Is this normal? Is it some bug?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am also suprised by the memory requirements.